# Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles works in console host but I get a 404 in IIS on file requests

Tags: iis, owin, static-files, katana

I have Microsoft.Owin.FileServer (v2.1.0) set up in my Owin pipeline, and setting up FileServerOptions with EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true works great for showing the directory contents in both my console host and iisexpress.

It's when I try to view a particular file (so, the StaticFiles part) I have problems in iisexpress. Still works great in the console host, but in iisexpress I get a 404:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
- The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
- The URL contains a typographical error.
- A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.
```

I do have the latest Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb referenced in the web host.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` didn't work for me (VS2013, IIS Express).

Forcing all requests to use the Owin pipeline did:

(in web.config)

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests worked while I had SignalR in the Owin pipeline. When I removed it, I had to add the handler you show here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Zac, saved me from more head aches. But why is this necessary, at all?

Comment: I don't know exactly.  I assume there is some conflict between modules in the older ASP.NET HTTP modules pipline and the newer Owin pipline.  For new projects, ASP.NET 5 has a different mechanism for static files: https://wipdeveloper.com/2015/04/02/asp-net-5-and-static-files/

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following setting:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

to get the module that Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb automatically registers to run for routes like *.txt, *.js that IIS was assuming were static files to run through the Owin pipeline.

This setting does have performance implications for actual static files, but this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just struggled with this for the last couple of hours, adding the handler below did work however I don't believe this was the correct approach, it caused `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)` to be invoked twice.

`<add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>`

I did some reading and found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline
which then lead me to use `UseStageMarked()`.

So now my call to `UseStaticFiles()` is followed by a called to `UseStageMarker()` like so:

```
appBuilder.UseStaticFiles();
//allows owin middlwares to be executed earlier on in the pipeline.
appBuilder.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

There is a very good read on it here:

You can find `UseStageMarker` inside the `Microsoft.Owin` package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin/

I hope this helps someone else.

Thanks

Steve