# Can OWIN Fileserver middleware allow sub folders

Tags: owin

In a new OWIN project I'm using

```
appBuilder.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
{
    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\public"),
});
```

Which serves up files in the public folder in my project just fine. But if I make a css folder and put a file in there it doesn't work (404) - I don't want directory browsing, but I do want files from sub folders served up but I can't see an option for that. Am I missing something to do this?

Comment: It's also not working for a file in the same folder now... (style.css)

Comment: Argh!  This was the problem which has been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071894/microsoft-owin-staticfiles-works-in-console-host-but-i-get-a-404-in-iis-on-file

Answer (score 0):

That should just work. The URL needs to include the sub folder name. e.g. `/css/my.css`

Comment: That's what I assumed. Sadly it just 404s it :(

Comment: When in doubt, turn on directory browsing to see what's wrong with the directory structure.